# Пробелы в поле с типом данных char

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Допустим есть столбец `емейл` типа `char` и количеством символов 50.
Когда идет запись в БД в это поле, то, допустим, `емейл` состоит из 10 символов. Когда смотришь в БД, строка добита полностью 40-ми пробелами.

Как сделать, чтобы строка не дополнялась пробелами? Иначе при выводе из БД приходится применять `replace`.

Comment: используйте для столбца таблицы тип данных `varchar` вместо `char`

Comment: извиняюсь за вопрос, а в postgresql нет `trim`?

Comment: не в курсе, но каждый раз это прописывать, тоже я вам скажу занятие не из лучших практик

Answer (score 3):

Из [офф. документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-character.html):

> character(n), char(n)  fixed-length, **blank padded**

Измените тип данных столбца с `char` на `varchar`. Например:

```sql
create table addr (mail char(50)) 

insert into addr values ('zhena@zhizni.net') 

alter table addr alter column mail type varchar(50) using rtrim(mail) 

select '>>'||mail||'<<' mail from addr
```

Вывод:

```
mail
--------------------
>>zhena@zhizni.net<<
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=366f30d410c2ad3fcc6d963b1d5a0f86)

Comment: Да да, уже изменил, спасибо и вам.

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт SQL требует, чтобы неиспользуемые символы в типах `CHARACTER VARYING(N)` и `CHARACTER(N)`добивались пробелами. Это странное поведение, но таков уж стандарт. В *PostgreSQL* вы можете использовать расширение, типы `CHARACTER VARYING` (без `N`) и `TEXT`. Если вы хотите добавить условие по длине, используйте `CHECK`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  email TEXT
, CONSTRAINT emai_length CHECK (CHARACTER_LENGTH(email) <= 50)
);
```

Документация:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-character.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек. Я этого не видел в документации теперь понял что у CHAR фиксированная длинна. Раньше об этом не задумывался строил БД на MySql, а об этом не задумывался.